# RDP Client showing different screen (related to SConfig) on VM Startup

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-vm

1. I have created a VM of Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition x64 bit in Central US.
2. I have installed the IIS Web Server while provisioning the VM itself by selecting the custom script extension at Advanced Menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB4Hb.png

3. I have selected the PowerShell script stored in the Storage account container.

```
import-module servermanager
add-windowsfeature web-server -includeallsubfeature
add-windowsfeature Web-Asp-Net45
add-windowsfeature NET-Framework-Features
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Pa4.png

4. Enabled the Ports **`Http (80)`**, **`Https (443)`**, and **`RDP (3389)`**.
   There is no proxy.
5. When I Open the RDP Client:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bjNI.png

In other 2 VMs created in Same VNet and of Same OS Same IIS Web server PS Script installed using Custom script extension while provisioning the VMs, able to get the Windows GUI through RDP:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDjA5.png

**Note**:

1. I have also done the same process in 3 VMs created in the Same Virtual Network, with the Same Custom Script Extension selected that installs IIS Web Server but only one of them is not working in the RDP Client (VM GUI Desktop is not showing other than SConfig command prompt).
2. Deleted all the 3 VMs and created again to check if any fault of mine while creating the VMs but same result.
3. In the VM Index Menu > Run Command > I have run the command `Set-SConfig -AutoLaunch $False`. Still, same Command prompt occurring instead of Windows Desktop GUI.

**In Short**:

1. Windows 2022 Data center Azure Edition
2. All 3 VMs in same virtual network
3. All 3 VMs in same availability set
4. All VM's are installed with IIS Web Server while provisioning using Custom Script Extension in the Advanced Menu of VM Creation. (That Script details given above).
5. Location (optional) - Central US
6. Enabled the Ports 80, 443 and 3389 while creating the VMs.

Subscription - Free Trail

> Can you open a PowerShell or CMD prompt and provide the output of the following command for each: wmic os get caption, OperatingSystemSKU, Version, BuildNumber, OSProductSuite –
> Greg Askew

wmic os get caption - Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition
OS Version - Najor - 10, Minor - 0, Build - 20348, Revision - 0

SKU Size:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKzkg.png

Comment: Please add what you are expecting instead. The screenshot you provided seems completely normal.

Comment: Hey @GregAskew, I have added complete data, Please check and upvote.

Comment: Can you open a PowerShell or CMD prompt and provide the output of the following command for each: `wmic os get caption, OperatingSystemSKU, Version, BuildNumber, OSProductSuite`

Comment: Hope I have provided information required in your ask by updating in the question itself @GregAskew

Comment: I don't see OperatingSystemSKU, and there is only one entry, not two.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same OS - not the same version at least. SConfig is the default screen coming up on the CORE version, the other 2 seem not to be core but to be the GUI versions. Here basically you end up on a "real" desktop.

Only logical conclusion is that they were created from different OS images. Simple like that.

Comment: Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition - This is the OS same for all the 3 VMs.

Comment: They were created on the Same OS Image

Comment: @hasher: Seems they are not, otherwise you would have included screenshots of both that show the same OperatingSystemSKU from supplied command at the command prompt. Also `dism /Online /Get-CurrentEdition`

Comment: I don't know these command lets to show you the desired results but I'm pretty sure that I have created them with the same OS because I created as well as my colleagues created the same, they too got the same error.

Comment: And we got the solution that it's not because of the OS difference, its because of the availability set quota in free trail subscription.

Comment: If the input, output, errors, efforts on solving the error (all) are given in the question by any user, don't discourage users by downvoting the question.